# AbpFeatures and AbpEditions

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

Can anyone please tell me what are the uses of the tables(AbpFeatures and AbpEditions) in Boilerplate Framework Application(Asp.net core with Angular).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[Edition Management](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/Edition-Management):

> Most **SaaS** (multi-tenant) applications have **editions** (packages) that have different **features**. Thus, they can provide different **price and feature options** to their tenants (customers).
>
> **Edition** is a simple entity that represents an edition (or package) of the application.

[Feature Management](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Feature-Management):

> ASP.NET Boilerplate provides a **feature system** to make it easier. We can **define** features, **check** if a feature is **enabled** for a tenant and **integrate** feature system to other ASP.NET Boilerplate concepts (like [authorization](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Authorization) and [navigation](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Navigation)).
>
> A feature can be:
>
> - "true" or "false" — **enabled** or **disabled** (for an edition or for a tenant), or
> - an **arbitrary value**.

Usage:

```cs
[RequiresFeature("ExportToExcel")]
public async Task<FileDto> GetReportToExcel(...)
{
    // ...
}
```